Is it against any international laws or laws of Denmark for residents in Greenland to receive money from the U.S. and then vote to join the U.S.?
Greenland is an autonomous territory of the Kingdom of Denmark. My understanding is that Greenland residents should have the right to choose to become an independent country or join another country? Correct me if I am wrong.
However, suppose the U.S. pays each Greenlander $1 million (Greenland has a population of less than 60,000) and ask them to vote to join the U.S., will it be against any international law or law of the Kingdom of Denmark? If the majority vote "Yes", is it legal for the U.S. to claim the Greenland without the permission from the Kingdom of Denmark?

the right to choose to become an independent country or join another country would be sovereignty, not autonomy

While I don’t know if it’s true of Denmark specifically, many countries have laws prohibiting paying people to vote.

"My understanding is that Greenland residents should have the right to choose to become an independent country or join another country?" What is this understanding based on?

@MikeScott but in many of those cases, a goodwill payment that is explicitly independent of the recipient's voting is permitted, even though it will obviously influence the outcome of the election.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-determination

I am aware that certain American politicians have tried to advocate for annexing Greenland. Has any of them made this proposal in particular? If not, I don't see the motivation for asking about this speculative scenario.

@NoOne Thanks. Is it possible to add that source as a link to the question body? It would improve the question, make it more self-explaining to future visitors while comments can be cleaned at any moment.

@NoOne: Your Wikipedia page on self-determination does not say that regions have the right to choose to become an independent country or join another country. In fact, it specifically says that no right to secession is recognized.

Actually, it is allowed (cribbed from answer): As part of the self-rule law of 2009 (section §21), Greenland can declare full independence if they wish to pursue it, but it would have to be approved by a referendum among the Greenlandic people.  So... could they be bribed to vote yes in an already allowed referendum?

Maybe the US could buy Greenland from Denmark, like they bought Alaska from Russia.

First Greenland would need to declare independence, after which they can do whatever.
Wiki on Greenlandic independence

As part of the self-rule law of 2009 (section §21), Greenland can declare full independence if they wish to pursue it, but it would have to be approved by a referendum among the Greenlandic people. A poll in 2016 showed that there was a clear majority (64%) for full independence among the Greenlandic people, but a poll in 2017 showed that there was a clear opposition (78%) if it meant a fall in living standards.

Note this only applies to Greenland. Other independence movements might have different issues, e.g. Scotland can't just declare independence from the UK, and any attempt to do so would result in the UK military going in to reassert its sovereignty. The US could still bribe Scots to attempt this, then send in its own military to defeat the UK's, of course.

"and any attempt to do so would result in the UK military going in to reassert its sovereignty": unlikely.

Very likely, given what happened in Spain, 2017.

The situations in Spain and Scotland have almost nothing in common.

@phoog That's your unqualified opinion. They have in common that they're part of another country, and a percentage of their populations wants independence. The British Parliament allowed Scotland a referendum of independence; this is seen by most english politicians as a huge mistake, so allowing a second one it's not on the table. If Scotland decided to declare independence without Westminster's approval things could get... tricky. Situations in Spain and Scotland have nothing in common until they do have a lot in common.

@Rekesoft when someone states a contentious opinion without giving reasons, even when prompted, there is no need to talk to them further.

@Rekesoft the historical context of Scotland's union with England is significantly different from the history of Catalonia; Scotland has a fundamentally different legal relationship with the United Kingdom from Catalonia's with the Kingdom of Spain; and the degree and nature of conflict around independence are very different both historically and today. While it's certainly possible to imagine scenarios in which the UK would use military force against Scottish separatists, it's far from a foregone conclusion that they would meet "any attempt to [declare independence]" with military force.

That doesn't answer the question very much.  The question isn't what they can do after independence, it is whether it is legal beforehand for another country to bribe voters to vote for independence, during the referendum which you did manage to unearth the allowance for.  So 1. allowed referendum - check, 2. many jurisdictions have anti vote-buying laws 3. many have foreign interference laws 4. UN/EU do seem to have anti vote-buying rules 5. bribe would have to be funded by US Congress.

@ItalianPhilosopher What if the bribe didn't come from the US government, but some rich American? Musk could give each Greenlander $1,000 out of his pocket change.

@Barmar That's a different question now...Musk isn't the U.S. government

@Starship Not officially, but he's a close confidant of the President-elect, and could easily act as a proxy for the US. Imagine if they arrange for him to receive some tax savings, and covertly agree that he'll funnel that money to the Greenland bribes. This would hide the government involvement in the scheme.

@Barmar This is Soros's department.

Of course they can take $1,000 each and then not vote about independence or vote against it. Or ask for a million and repeat.

@gnasher729 I suppose what he'd have to do is promise to give $1,000 to each resident after the referendum on succession succeeds. So he's not bribing any specific voters, but everyone has an incentive to vote the way he wants.
